# Django multiple many to many relationships not working

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

Are multiple many-to-many relationships possible in a single class?  Here is my thinking:

A policy can be translated into many Languages
A Language can list many policies

A country can list many policies (even in multiple languages)
A policy can be discussed in many countries

I am using django, python3, and mysql and I am going in circles.  The many to many relationships seem to be the problem.

Many to many through table not working:
        languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, through="Policy_Detail")

steps for circular error message:

alias p3="python3"

p3 manage.py migrate
error message: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'policytracker_country' already exists")

dropped policytracker_country and all other policytracker tables

typed in p3 manage.py make migrations
No changes detected

typed in p3 manage.py migrate
(1051, "Unknown table 'PolicyDB.policytracker_flag'")

mysql> show tables;
+------------------------------+
| Tables_in_PolicyDB           |
+------------------------------+
| policytracker_country        |
| policytracker_events         |
| policytracker_policy_user    |
| policytracker_website        |
| policytracker_website_filter |
+------------------------------+

added policytracker_flag and policytracker_label_links using MySql
(even though I don't refer to any of them in my code)
dropped all other policytracker tables

+----------------------------+
| Tables_in_PolicyDB         |
+----------------------------+
| policytracker_flag         |
| policytracker_label_links  |
+----------------------------+

p3 manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

p3 manage.py migrate

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'PolicyDB.policytracker_policy_detail' doesn't exist")
+------------------------------+
| Tables_in_PolicyDB           |
+------------------------------+
| auth_group                   |
| auth_group_permissions       |
| auth_permission              |
| auth_user                    |
| auth_user_groups             |
| auth_user_user_permissions   |
| django_admin_log             |
| django_content_type          |
| django_migrations            |
| policytracker_country        |
| policytracker_events         |
| policytracker_policy_user    |
| policytracker_website        |
| policytracker_website_filter |
+------------------------------+

Moved 'policytracker.policy_detail' model class before 'policytracker.policy' class
NameError: name 'Policy' is not defined

Moved it back
p3 manage.py makemigrations
no changes detected

p3 manage.py migrate
"Table 'policytracker_country' already exists"
...and we've come full circle - see first error message

What am I doing wrong?  Here's the models:

`class Website_Filter(models.Model):
            ...`

```
    class Language(models.Model):
        iso_language                    = models.CharField(max_length = 2, primary_key=True)
        flag_image_filename             = models.CharField(max_length = 10, default='en.png')
        nav_section_policy_list_title   = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default='Policies')
        ...

    class Country(models.Model):
        language_country_code           = models.CharField(max_length = 5, primary_key=True, default="en/ca")
        country_name                    = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    class Policy(models.Model):
        image_filename  = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
        start_date      = models.DateField(default = None)  
        languages       = models.ManyToManyField(Language, through="Policy_Detail")
        countries       = models.ManyToManyField(Country)

    class Policy_Detail(models.Model):
        policy            = models.ForeignKey(Policy)
        language          = models.ForeignKey(Language)   
        needs_translation = models.BooleanField(default = True)
        name              = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        description1      = models.TextField()
        description2      = models.TextField()
        description3      = models.TextField()
        twitter_handle    = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default='')
        subreddit         = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default='')

    class Website(models.Model):
        name            = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique=True)
        ip_address      = models.GenericIPAddressField()
        link            = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        is_pending      = models.BooleanField()
        is_allowed      = models.BooleanField()                

    class Official_Site(Website):
        policy = models.ForeignKey(Policy_Detail)

    class Interviews(Website):
        policy = models.ForeignKey(Policy_Detail)

    class Frequently_Asked_Questions(Website):
        policy = models.ForeignKey(Policy_Detail)

    class Articles(Website):
        policy = models.ForeignKey(Policy_Detail)

    class Books(Website):
        policy = models.ForeignKey(Policy_Detail)

    class Petitions(Website):
        policy = models.ForeignKey(Policy_Detail)

    class Actions(Website):
        policy = models.ForeignKey(Policy_Detail)

    class Rallies(Website):
        policy = models.ForeignKey(Policy_Detail)

    class Events(models.Model):
        policy = models.ForeignKey(Policy_Detail)
        event_date      = models.DateField(null=True)
        ...

    class Policy_User(models.Model):
        country           = models.ForeignKey(Country)
        username          = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default="Anonymous")

    class Vote(models.Model):
        policy            = models.ForeignKey(Policy)
        p_user            = models.ForeignKey(Policy_User)
        voting_date       = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
        week_number       = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
        vote_code         = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Yes, multiple many to many relationships are possible in a single class. Could you be more specific about what you kind of trouble you are having? What are the exact error messages you're getting, and what do you mean specifically by 'implementing'? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ChidG see edited question

Comment: @ChidG  In my Policy class I changed languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, through="Policy_Detail") to models.ManyToManyField(Language, through="PolicyLanguage"), ran p3 makemigrations, p3 migrate and got the error:  

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'PolicyDB.policytracker_policy_detail' doesn't exist")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks more like a problem with migrations being out of sync with the state of the database. I don't think the many to many fields are the main issue although they may exacerbate it by making the migrations more 
complex.

While you could potentially solve this problem by running individual migrations, manually marking migrations as complete in the database, or other fiddly methods, here's the most straightforward and clean way to solve the problem, and will work for you because you don't have any data in the database yet.

1. Drop all tables from your database.
2. Delete the `migrations` directory in all of your Django app directories.
3. Run `manage.py makemigrations` and then `manage.py migrate` again.